# Unable to push data from kafka topic into clickhouse

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse, ksqldb

I have data in STRING format in kafka topic, Now when i am creating clickhouse tables
like this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS conv_kafka;
CREATE TABLE conv_kafka (
id String,
attachments Array(String)
)
ENGINE = Kafka SETTINGS
    kafka_broker_list = 'localhost:9092',
    kafka_topic_list = 'test',
    kafka_group_name = 'group_test',
    kafka_format = 'CSV',
    kafka_row_delimiter = '\n';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS conv;
CREATE TABLE conv (
    id String,
    attachments Array(String)
)ENGINE = MergeTree() ORDER BY (id);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS conv_mview;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW conv_mview TO conv AS SELECT * FROM conv_kafka;
```

No data is coming in clickhouse.
PS: I have tried JSONEachRow, TSV formats.
Data is coming in case of JSONEachRow, but coming all values as null.

Background Info:
I took the data from mongodb into kafka topic and because of this the format is STRING there. Creating stream with 'DELIMITED' or 'JSON' format is also not working. in 'SHOW STREAMS' its showing format is json or delimited but topic format remain same i.e. STRING

Comment: is your clickhouse instance in the same host as kafka?

Comment: Yes probelm is with the kafka_format